# How to avoid duplicates from csv uploads

Tags: javascript, csv, google-apps-script

I been working in the next Script:

```
function test(){
  var archivos = DriveApp.getFolderById("someFolderID").getFiles();
  var appendTo = SpreadsheetApp.openById("someSpreadsheetID");
  var ss = appendTo.setActiveSheet(appendTo.getSheets()[0]);

  Logger.log(ss.getName())
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvFile);

  while(archivos.hasNext()){
    var archivo = archivos.next()
    var csvFile = archivo.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    var numRows = ss.getLastRow() +1;

    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvFile);
    ss.getRange(numRows , 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData); 
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }

}
```

And I will need to run it Weekly Uploading a New csv. each time.

So, the question is: How can I do that without uploading again the old and already uploaded files? Like a onetime condition.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry -- I'm not to sure what you are asking. Do you upload a file every week then run this script? Are you wanting it to run automatically?

Comment: You use a code like this [one](https://ctrlq.org/code/19975-move-file-between-folders) to move files to a subfolder after you have processed it.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to record the last time you performed your backup in the script in [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service):

```
    ...
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
  PropertiesService().getScriptProperties().setProperty("Last Backup", String(new Date().getTime()));
}
```

You would check this timestamp in your script (defaulting to 0 in case the property isn't set), and ensure that you only work on files that have been modified since the last backup.

```
  ...
  var ps = PropertiesService().getScriptProperties();
  var lastUpdateTime = ps.getProperty("Last Backup") || 0;
  while (archivos.hasNext()) {
    var archivo = archivos.next();
    if (archivo.getLastUpdated().getTime() - lastUpdateTime > 0) {
      /*
        Get as a CSV file, append to spreadsheet, etc.
       */
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
  ps.setProperty("Last Backup", String(new Date().getTime()));
}
```

I've given the sample code above assuming that this is the only script that will be used (i.e. `getScriptProperties()` is the most useful storage device), but depending on how this script will be used, one of the other two may make more sense for you.